# JS On Close Redirect

Tags: javascript

We have a chat script for support. I was wondering if it is possible to redirect to a survey page either in the current window or the parent after the user has closed or tries to close the chat page using JS? I've done some research but all I can find is stuff on reloading the parent or alerts.

Thanks

Comment: Built-in pop-up blockers will likely deny this. They can only be opened when handling certain events that are triggered by the user -- `unload` likely isn't one of those permitted events. So, while you can write the script for it, the window probably won't actually show.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of `unload()` event in javascript. The event gets triggered when the user tries to close the browser.  Refer the [link here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp)

Comment: Doesn't look like that is supported by Chrome or Safari =(

Answer (score 0):

You might also look into onbeforeunload - [see here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhtbtum.php) - though I don't know if it is supported any better than onunload.  One thing to keep in mind with both is that it refers to unloading the document rather than the window.  So, closing the window isn't the only thing that triggers them - for instance navigating to another page.